# parented bone seems to move or break when exported to fbx

Tags: bones, parent, .fbx

I have a person and a stick. The stick has 1 bone, and it is parented to the hand bone of the person.

It looks great in Blender, but in Unity or 3D viewer it is broken.

The stick in Unity is in the wrong place, instead of in the hand it's behind the hand and in 3D viewer it just doesn't move.

Below is a screenshot in Unity and Blender:

[image: explanation]

Below is a screenshot of 3D viewer:

[image]

Here is my file:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When exporting to other files,
It is better to have a single armature (avatar).
In the current file, the armature is nested in the armature.
In the 3D viewer, the armature must be a single armature or bugs will occur.

[image]]

Also, since the stick is now also given an avatar,
I would recommend the idea of putting a bone for the stick in the right hand of the armature.
[image]]

Select the bones for ease of adjustment and temporarily put the camera in rest mode.
[image]

Weight paint the object you want to move and the bones you added.
[image]

To be sure, also applique the scale of the object.
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Awsome :)

How did you get rid of armature.001 for the stick. because if i just create a single bone, it comes with the armature object and i cant seem to get the bone without it.

Comment: @learn_css
I believe deletion can be done from the 3D view.
Basically, the bones for the hand should be placed under the hand.
Do not think of the stick as a weapon, but rather think of it as a part of the body, like a hair part, and assign the bones and the stick to it.

Please download my file and check the position of the bones in the outliner.